# How to change id of nodes in igraph?

Tags: r, igraph

I have a tree such as:

```
library(igraph)
tree<- graph.empty(15)
tree <- tree + path(5,4,3,1,2)
tree <- tree + path(8,7,6,5)
tree <- tree + path(15,14,13,12,11,10,9,5)

root <- V(tree)[igraph::degree(tree, mode="out")==0]
plot(tree, vertex.size=6, edge.arrow.size=0.1, 
     layout=layout.reingold.tilford(tree, mode="in", root=root))
```

Vertex ids are given by input order:

```
V(tree)
Vertex sequence:
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

[image]

I would like to re-number the ids so that the root is 1. Using the `name` attribute I get:

```
# label the root as 1, and the rest as 2...N
root <- V(tree)[igraph::degree(tree, mode="out")==0]
V(tree)$name[V(tree) != root] <- 2:vcount(tree)
V(tree)$name[V(tree) == root] <- 1
root <- V(tree)[igraph::degree(tree, mode="out")==0]
plot(tree, vertex.size=6, edge.arrow.size=0.1,
     layout=layout.reingold.tilford(tree, mode="in", root=root))
```

[image]

But the ids are unchanged:

```
V(tree)
Vertex sequence:
 [1]  2  1  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15

V(tree)$name
 [1]  2  1  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

Is there a way to re-assign ids so that I can directly play with them instead of with their names? It should give:

```
V(tree)
Vertex sequence:
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

Comment: You can permute them with `permute()`.

Comment: thanks Gabor. What about if the original id's are not 1,2.. N but random integers?

Comment: That cannot happen because igraph vertex IDs are always consecutive integers from the range [1; N] in R.

Comment: So when V(g) shows me numbers like 985 and so on, it is showing me the name instead? And then the id can be seen by the position every node holds in the V(g) sequence?

Answer (score 0):

Following Gabor Csardi's idea here is an example: Suppose we want to change the node IDs using `permute` to sort them in decreasing degree order:

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(1)
g = erdos.renyi.game(20,0.2)
V(g)$name = letters[1:20]
g2 = permute(g, Matrix::invPerm(order(degree(g), decreasing = T)))
```